# Error referencia de objeto

Tags: c#, excepciones

A la hora de rellenar una lista en un ViewModel me salta el error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

El ViewModel es este:

```
public class vmMovimientosParking
    {
    public vmMovimientosParking()
    {
        List <tipoPersonal> tipoPersonal = new List<tipoPersonal>();
    }


    public List<Empresa> ListaDepartamento { get; set; }
    public List<MovimientosParking> marcaje { get; set;}

    public List <tipoPersonal> tipoPersonal { get; set; }

}
```

Donde lo llamo :

```
foreach (var m in coches)
            {
                resultadoProvisional.AddRange(marcaje.Where(ma => ma.Matricula == m.MAT).ToList());
                tipoPersonal nuevo = new tipoPersonal();
                nuevo.numEmp = m.NUM;
                nuevo.tipoEmp = m.TIPO;
                nuevo.nombre = m.NOMBRE;
                nuevo.apellidos = m.APELLIDOS;
                modelo.tipoPersonal.Add(nuevo); //Aqui salta el error
            }
```

Y el objeto tipoPersonal:

```
public class tipoPersonal
{
    public int numEmp;
    public string tipoEmp;
    public string nombre;
    public string apellidos;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta claro que el mensaje de error se produce porque hay un objeto que esta en `null`, entonces cuando lo accedes falla

Veo en el codigo varios lugare donde se podria producir esto, pero el primero que noto es la propiedad `marcaje` veo que no la instancias en ninguna lado, pero si la utilizas cuando generas el Where() de linq

Que pasa si separas un poco el codigo usando

```
var marcajeList = marcaje.Where(ma => ma.Matricula == m.MAT).ToList()

resultadoProvisional.AddRange(marcajeList);
```

detecta cuando falla en que linea se detiene he inspecciona las variables para ver cual esta en `null`

Esto mismo que comento sucede con `modelo` no veo donde lo instancias, ademas debes instanciar la propiedad no una nueva lista

```
public class vmMovimientosParking
{
    public vmMovimientosParking()
    {
        this.tipoPersonal = new List<tipoPersonal>();
    }


    public List<Empresa> ListaDepartamento { get; set; }
    public List<MovimientosParking> marcaje { get; set;}

    public List <tipoPersonal> tipoPersonal { get; set; }

}
```

valida como use `this` en el constructor

Comment: si era el this en el consrtuctor, gracias